# animation starts when tilting

Tags: iphone, animation, acceleration, tilt

i like to start this animation when tilting. it doesn't, so i suppose some essential code is missing. please help:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
 flap.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie1.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie2.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie3.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie4.png"], 
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie5.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie6.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie7.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie8.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie9.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed: @"ronnie10.png"],nil];
 [flap setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
 flap.animationDuration = 2;
 [flap startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As named, `-accelerometer:didAccelerate:` will be fired whenever the accelerometer detects a change in acceleration. Hence, during your tilting probably this method will be executed dozens of times. But every time it is executed, *you reset the animation*, so the net effect is as if no animation happened.

You have to (1) analyze the `acceleration` to check whether it is really tilting, and (2) check `[flap isAnimating]` and *don't* reset the animation if `YES`.

Comment: KennyTm, how would you 'analyze the acceleration to check whether it is really tilting'?